# Object is null, although is has been initialized

Tags: java, arrays, object, null

I have following code:

```
public class GameCanvas extends JPanel {

private GridField[][] grid;
private int x, y;
private int fieldSize;

public GameCanvas(int rows, int cols, int fieldSize)
{
    this.grid = new GridField[cols][rows];
    this.x = cols;
    this.y = rows;
    this.fieldSize = fieldSize;
}

...
}
```

Here is the definition of the GridField class:

```
public class GridField {

private FieldType fieldType;    

public GridField() {
    fieldType = FieldType.EMPTY;
}

public FieldType getFieldType() {
    return fieldType;
}

public void setFieldType(FieldType fieldType) {
    this.fieldType = fieldType;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to access the "grid" object, the compiler says it's null, although I have initialized it in the constructor of the class.

I did a little check:

```
if(grid[xSize][ySize] == null) {
  System.out.println("Grid[x][y] is null");
}
```

It printed out exactly what I expected - null.

I'm coming to Java from C# background so I might have missed something. I believe, it's a trivial mistake, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance, for any hint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.grid = new GridField[cols][rows];
```

The above code only initializes the array. You also need to initialize each array elements with `objects` of `GridField`.

Probably something like this: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = new GridField();
    }
}
```

> I'm coming to Java from C# background so I might have missed
>   something.

This way of initialization is no different in `C#`. So, if you initialized arrays like this in `C#`, then probably you missed something there also. Note the comments from @JonSkeet.

Comment: And note that this isn't a difference between Java and C# - the OP would have seen exactly the same behaviour in C#.

Comment: Thank You! I thought it would be a trivia. I just looped through each element of the array and initialized it with new GridField and it worked. Thank You!

Comment: which would be liks so: `grid[0][0] = new GridField();`, plus you can use nested `for` loops to populate it, if it can be populated incrementally.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I thought it's not a problem related to Java, it was just my lack of knowledge..

Comment: @jam40jeff.. AFAIK, there is no such thing as `struct` in Java.

Comment: @jam40jeff I would have done so - in C#, but from what I know, Java doesn't have structs, or does it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I read it backwards and was thinking you were coming to `C#` from `Java`.  I guess I should have looked at the tags more closely.  Ignore my (now deleted) comment. :)

Comment: @Downvoter.. Anything wrong in the post that you want to point out? Please add a comment on your downvote.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, I marked it, I had to wait for some time, until I could mark it.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.grid = new GridField[cols][rows];
```

This only initialize the array but you don't have elements.

Elements in the array are pointing to null

Comment: Well, the *elements* in the array are null. There's really no such thing as a null object.

Comment: @null.. Note that elements inside the array are references, and they cannot be null. In fact you should say, elements in array are pointing to null.